# How to recursively create the full ancestry of a given record in BigQuery

Tags: sql, recursion, google-bigquery

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `parentId`. I want to recursively find all of a given record's ancestors. So, if I have record 145 and its parent is 233 and 233's parent is 651, my results would be something like below, given I only have id 145 available to me (this assumes that for root records, the parentId = 0).

```
| id  | parentId |
 ----- ----------
| 651 |     0    |
| 233 |    651   |
| 145 |    233   |
```

How can I recursively do this query with SQL against my BigQuery table? I spent some time looking around on SO but each answer seemed overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new-ish `recursive` feature in BigQuery this can be accomplished with the below:

```sql
with recursive ancestors as (
    select * from `dataset.MyTable` 
    where id = 145
    union all
    select m.* 
    from `dataset.MyTable` as m, ancestors as a
    where m.id = a.parentOrderId
) 
select * from ancestors;
```

I found this after reading a post by Christianlauer [here](https://medium.com/codex/using-with-recursive-in-bigquery-sql-e593325f33f).

Hopefully this Q&A can make this technique easier to find.

Comment: Google's documentation, announcement and usage of the feature:

1. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause

2. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#February_02_2022

3. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/bigquery-loves-user-friendly-sql